# How to implement the movement system from SharkBite Bay Adventure?

Tags: movement, godot-4

I'm using Godot Engine 4. The game *SharkBite Bay Adventure* is a top-down 2D car game, which can be properly played in [Bluemaxima's Flashpoint](https://bluemaxima.org/flashpoint/downloads/) (this app has 2 versions: you can download the lightweight one (*Infinity)* in the bottom of the link's page) or look at the end of this question for the SWF — in case you need to get a gasp of how it works — with a very specific movement system different from other ordinary top-down 2D car games.

In other top-down 2D car games you see either of the following movement systems:

- Click or press spacebar to accelerate and rotate with the mouse pointer
- Press the up arrow or spacebar to accelerate and use left/right to rotate
- Or similiar to these

SharkBite Bay Adventure has a very cool unique movement mechanism, but the game is short, sadly. Anyway, you can note the following aspects in SharkBite Bay Adventure:

- To move the vehicle, you use the 4 directionals. Each of them moves towards one direction.
- Moving to a direction causes a rotation tween. One tween from a next direction input cancels the previous tween.
- You can combine directionals to move towards a diagonal angle.
- You can mess around with directionals, allowing for drifts.

So using Godot I basically create a subtype of `CharacterBody2D` (previously named kinematic body in Godot 3). I can detect whether the player pressed a directional using `InputMap` IIRC. There is probably API for tweening entity properties, such as `rotation`. But, other than that, what is the logic for implementing this movement system? What are the steps?

#### SharkBite Bay Adventure download

To get a gasp of the game, if you can already run Flash at full performance and don't need Flashpoint, here's a SWF:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k_gb-3qUnIPbRbyl6oeU1ok9baFMmLMu/view?usp=sharing

Ruffle currently runs the game slowly, so I recommend sticking to either of the options above.

#### SharkBite Bay Adventure video

I didn't want to show a video of the game because it's not clear how the car moves, but I'm putting a short here anyway demonstrating the car drifting.

https://youtu.be/NeFYqiG9qro

Comment: I suggest you replace the download link with a GIF or link to a video with sample gameplay. It's faster for people to watch a video than downloading and executing a game they have never heard about, provided they own the software needed to play it.

Comment: @liggiorgio I'm afraid a video won't be useful as it's difficult to see how the car is moving. I can put a link, but I'm not sure it'll help understanding the movement system.